# Updating Broadcom Wifi driver 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, broadcom

As many others I ran into a problem with my Broadcom wifi driver on 12.04. Following the instructions at the Broadcom website [Compile Broadcom wifi driver](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt), I successfully made it work...well, almost.
The last bit of the instructions tells me that to permanently replace the old driver (i.e. load new driver at boot time), I should do the following:

```
$> cp wl.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless 
$> depmod -a
```

This bit doesn't seem to work, and I have to manually `insmod` the driver each time I reboot my laptop.

Any ideas what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

It is far preferable to install the version of the driver tweaked for Ubuntu rather than compile a one-size-maybe-fits-all from source code. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

You should be all set.